# Questions surrounding Bilam's death

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, death, mattos, bilam

In Parshas Matos (Bamidbar 31:8) it says וְאֵת בִּלְעָם בֶּן-בְּעוֹר הָרְגוּ בֶּחָרֶב.

Did Bilam do anything to avoid getting killed? What did he do? And who actually killed him?

Comment: Please explain your question.. what exactly are you asking? What are you trying to understand?

Comment: Are you asking about the the verse before this verse says? Are you asking about a midrash? Are you asking for historical data? Do you have reason to believe that Bilam did not try to avoid getting killed?

Comment: Gershon, your questions sound like riddle which you know the answer to.  Why would you even believe there is a question?  What did the 5 kings do to avoid getting killed?  The site can handle a question that is well formed, and has some data as to what is being asked.

Comment: Sorry - this question was not asked as a riddle, and I did not remember the answer that Alex gave, it was a question to gain knowledge, which you would prefer that I did not gain.

Comment: Gershon, there's no need to take it as personal rejection, and certainly not on the part of the whole community, when one person challenges your question. Please, let's try to avoid getting into a flame war. (I know this thread is still far from that now, but I'd like to nip any potential for one in the bud.)

Comment: It's always good to put whatever you can into the question to explain what's motivating it, to help people understand where you're coming from and what information may already be available.

Comment: Issac - my question was just that - a question based on seeing the Posuk and trying to know if there are any more details. Why is it that I get the feeling that people are looking to squash any question?????

Comment: I would like to know what is motivating Avi to request that my questions be closed?

Comment: Gershon, the reason I don't understand, is because based on the verse of the chumash one could answer that atleast on of the 12,001 men sent from verse 31:6 killed Bilam, along with all the men of Midian and the 5 kings, and what Bilam did to defend himself is an unnknown.  But I'm sure you knew that, even though you didn't put that knowledge into the question.

Comment: But, @avi, frequently _midrashim_ flesh out history. I don't think it's unreasonable to ask whether anyone knows of a _midrash_ about a particular historical event.

Comment: @msh210: it might be, then, that it would have garnered less (or no) objection had the question been worded something like this: "The Torah says that [citation of the pasuk]. Do we know any other details about how this occurred?"

Comment: It seems like questions are picked apart as if it is a Gemara.

Comment: Gershon, the Gemara (and even more so the Mishna and Torah before it) required a great deal of picking apart partly because it was written so tersely. The more detail you include in your questions in the first place, the fewer questions people will have in their minds when they encounter them, and the less you'll be asked to explain after the fact.

Comment: @msh210 I agree, if he asked about what the midrash said it would be clear.. but he doesn't. Which is why I asked to find out what he is talking about.  Also, the Rambam does not believe tha midrash is ever there to flesh out history. (And how could it?) Midrash is a complicated topic.  There are atleast four ways to answer a question on chumash. 1. With Tanaic midrashim, 2. what the verses say, 3. With Zohar based midrashim  4. Your own midrash.

Comment: @gershon would it kill you to flesh out what you are asking?

Answer (score 7):

Rashi (to Num. 31:6) quotes a Midrash that Bil'am used magic to lift himself and the Midianite kings into the air, but that Pinchas counteracted that by displaying the *tzitz*, causing them to all fall down - literally על חלליהם, "on the corpses" (of the other Midianites) as in v. 8.

Radak (to Josh. 13:22) cites this as well, and adds that Pinchas actually killed Bil'am.

Comment: Alex, do you know how Rashi explains the fact that the Torah specifically says they were killed by the sword?  I'm guessing that the midrash that Rashi and Radak  are quoting explains that bit.

Comment: @avi: he doesn't say, and neither does the Midrash he's citing (Bamidbar Rabbah 20:20 and 22:5) - it just says that they fell. Presumably, though, the fall didn't kill them, and the Jews - or, in the case of Bil'am, specifically Pinchas - finished them off by the sword. (Actually, the Gemara (Sanhedrin 106b, top) says that they carried out all four modes of judicial execution on Bil'am - which could mean that they first killed him by the sword and then did the other three things to his corpse, or that they did something like what Yakim Ish Tzroros did to himself (Bereishis Rabbah 65:22).)