# Midrashim concerning Balaam?

Tags: gentiles, midrash, nevua-prophecy

Where can I find Midrashim about Balaam the Gentile Prophet, who appears in this week's [Torah Portion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Torah_portion)?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9045/1059

Comment: Not a midrash but Rashi quotes Meseket Avodah Zarah (4b?) which gives over quite a colorful description of the kind of person Balaam was.

Comment: Not midrash, but interesting - http://www.livius.org/de-dh/deir_alla/deir_alla_inscr.html - Bilaam was known to the non-Jewish world and had non-Jewish traditions about him.

Answer (score 9):

- [Yalkut Shimoni](http://www.tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/balak.html) on Balak
- [Tanchuma](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14123&st=&pgnum=443&hilite=) on Balak
- [Midrash Rabah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&st=&pgnum=141) on Balak
- The gemaras mentioned in [Toldos Aharon](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=290) on Balak
- For a collection of all midrashim, you can look at R' Menachem Kasher's [Torah Shleimah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51442&st=&pgnum=7)

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know that Rabbi Kasher's Torah Shleima was available online!!!

Comment: @AdamMosheh hebrewbooks.org has most of it but not all

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine [once suggested to me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5227473#5227473) that I should try looking in [Shemos Rabba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_Rabbah) for the source of a Midrash that says he was in Egypt before the Exodus took place. Also, [he said](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5227453#5227453) that midrashim can be found in the Parshat Balak section in [Bamidbar Rabba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_Rabbah).